# Can't Install Ubuntu on my iMac

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, sound, mac

Apparently, my late-2009 iMac screwed up, and ruined everything. I was forced to reformat and I decided to use the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My iMac's SuperDrive is a jerk, so I plugged in my USB on my mother's MacBook, downloaded the ISO of Ubuntu and used the dd trick.

Installing Ubuntu resulted in a black screen of nothingness, and then the monitor would die out and I have to reset. I browsed through the Ubuntu forums and luckily found out about the `nomodeset` trick. Success was on my side, and I braced myself to shout victory. Unfortunately, the install hangs on this certain part with the OKs and fails.

I looked closer into it and found out that it was "Starting restore sound card(s') mixer state(s')" that failed.

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

@Goldgum Installing Ubuntu on a mac is sadly not as straight forward as it is for many windows based PC's. Since your particular mac computer does not appear to have a version that is officially supported by Mactel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages) this means you are doing an Unsupported Version install. it looks like the problems you are experiencing are fairly common and addressed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac). I would start with the support page and see if that has what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't really answer my question on how to fix the fail on "Starting restore sound card mixer states". If it's an inevitable problem, can I use an older Ubuntu version? Can I use a command or something? Please help me. I really want to use Ubuntu.

Comment: @Goldgum So I tried installing ubuntu on my iMac last night (also a 2009) had to do the nomodeset trick and everything seems to be ok. I then installed the previous lts version with similar results. Since you had no OS X on it when you did the initial install were you able to install refit? I am not sure if refit is absolutely mandatory or just needed for duel booting. This may be something to look into. I might try looking into that. If I have some spare time I will look into it too. Lets see if we can figure this out.

Comment: I'm still looking for help in this case.
Oh, and no. I don't have rEFIt installed and can't because I can only access my Mac's recovery mode.